# YARD @return not null

Tags: ruby, yard

How do I document a function that returns a value, while a null return value should raise a warning?

So currently the method below would be valid because yard allows for the specified type or void.

```
# @return [String]
def say_hello
  nil
end
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "a null return value should raise a warning"? Please be very specific -- if there is some action you're taking that causes YARD to generate a warning then include a [mre] that demonstrates precisely what you're talking about. Additionally, "yard allows for the specified type or void" is wrong because you are not specifying `@return [void]`.

Comment: @AlonDahari : What do you mean by _void_? We don't have the concept of voidness in plain Ruby. In your example, the method simply returns a data type of class `NilClass`, which is not a subclass of the one pomised in the comment (`String`), so the function does not match its specification of the comment, and as such is buggy.

Comment: @user1934428 In the context of yard, `void` means "[no meaningful value](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#declaring-types)" and is used for return values.

Comment: I don't know what a **meaningful** value is, as opposed to a **no meaningful** value, but in Ruby, every expression (and hence every function) returns an object of some class. You can't write a non-value returning function. How this is mapped to yard's idea of meaninglessness.

Comment: “No meaningful value” means the author does not care what the value is. It can be of any class.

Answer (score 4):

### Multiple Return Types in YARD

In YARD, the documentation provides a clear example of how to define multiple return types in the [Declaring Types](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#declaring-types) section. The same section says you're allowed to use the `void` meta-type to mean "no meaningful value," but since Ruby doesn't really have void methods I think that using `nil` as an expected return type (rather than `void`) is generally more semantically useful.

So, to document a return type of either `String` or `void`, you could express it thus:

```rb
# @return [String, void]
def say_hello
  nil
end
```

### Documentation Can't Enforce Contracts

YARD is for *documentation*, and doesn't actually enforce the types found in method signatures or contracts of any kind. So, your question seems like an X/Y problem because it's still up to the method or the caller to raise warnings or trigger an exception.

A better way to express what you seem to want is to use [Kernel#warn](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-warn) or [Kernel#raise](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) to address your expections. For example, consider:

```rb
# @param string [String]
# @raise [ArgumentError] argument missing or not String
# @return [String]
def say_hello string
  unless string.is_a? String
    raise ArgumentError, "string: #{string.class}, not String"
  end
  string
end
```

Ruby is a duck-typed language. Even though my example above seems like an improvement, it may still ultimately be a work-around for doing something non-Rubyish within your code. Without seeing your real code, this seems like a more reasonable way to enforce a contract between this method and an unknown caller. Of course, your mileage may certainly vary.